# Proof of linear independence of two functions

Tags: linear-algebra

In my class we're learning vector spaces, and in the text book there's an example with no solution and it goes like this:

> If the domain of functions $f$ and $g$ is $[-1,1]$ and if they are defined $f(x) = \arcsin\left(\displaystyle\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$ and $g(x) = \arctan(x)$, then $(f,g)$ is linearly independent?

I don't know how to prove this, if I can make a linear combination of one of them using the other it's dependent, but how should I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show that $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent, a very similar (but different) [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269668/linear-independence-of-sinx-and-cosx) was asked recently. Many techniques for solving that problem are also applicable here.

If you want to show that $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent, you have to show that $\arcsin(2x/(1+x^2))$ is some constant multiple of $\arctan x$.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem: Let $f$ be a function defined in an intrval $I$, and let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$ in $I$. Then every other derivative of $f$ in $I$ is of the form $F+costant$.

Now use above theorem to see that: $$\arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)= \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            -\pi-2\arctan(x) & \quad x \leq-1 \\
            2\arctan(x) & \quad -1\leq x\leq1 \\\pi-2\arctan(x) & \quad x\geq1
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Comment: So between [-1,1] it's linearly dependent, and [1, infinity] linearly independent.

Comment: @user55348: Yes. Try to look for the conditions which two functions are linierely dependent. See user1551's answer for the link or google it.

Comment: good lesson taught! +1

Answer (score 0):

$x=\tan g(x) \sin f(x)=2\tan g(x)/1+\tan^2g(x)=\sin 2g(x)$ so $f(x)=2g(x)$ (under suitable conditions.