# Prove that $\{ \sin(x), \sin^2(x), \sin^3(x)\}$ is linearly independent in $F(\Bbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $\{ \sin(x), \sin^2(x), \sin^3(x)\}$ is linearly independent in $F(\Bbb R)$.

I tried plugging in $\left\{ 0, \frac {\pi} {2}, \pi, \frac {3\pi}{2}\right\}$ but that doesn't work. How should I prove this?

Comment: what is $F(R)$  by the way?

Comment: I guess it is $\Bbb R^\Bbb R=\{\, f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\mid \,\}$

Comment: Try evaluating in $k\frac\pi6$ for $k=0,1,\ldots$, you are bound to find $3$ independent $3$-tuples soon.

Comment: But for a more insightful answer, see the "duplicate" (actually much more general) question.

Comment: Thanks, the other post makes sense.

Comment: You'd best follow the link above. Here's another one which is very similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/269668/8157

Answer (score 1):

Assume:
$$\sin(x)^3=A\sin(x)^2+B\sin(x)$$
then from $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $x=\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$:
$$1=A+B,\quad-1=A-B\quad\Rightarrow\quad A=0,\quad B=1$$
which implies:
$$\sin(x)^3=\sin(x)\quad\Rightarrow\quad \sin(x)^2=1\quad \forall x \ne n\pi$$

which is false.