# What is the space spanned by $a\cos x + b\sin x$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the case when $x = \pi/4$.

$\cos \pi/4 = 1 = \sin \pi/4$.

Now, if $a = 1$ and $b = -1$,
$a\cos x + b\sin x = 0 $(for non-zero a and b).

Does this imply that $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ ARE NOT linearly independent?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269668/linear-independence-of-sinx-and-cosx

Comment: Just a comment: $\cos \pi / 4 = \sqrt{2}/{2} = \sin \pi / 4$ not $1$

Answer (score 6):

The **functions** $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are linearly independent.  There are various ways to see this: I give a method which picks up on your own working.

First let
$$a\cos x+b\sin x=0\ ,$$
and make sure you understand that this is an equality of **functions**: that is, it means that the LHS is zero **for all values of** $x$.  Taking $x=\pi/4$, as you have done, shows that $a+b=0$; but taking say $x=0$ shows that $a=0$.  Solving these two equations gives $a=0$, $b=0$ as the only possibility,  and so $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are linearly independent.