# Equating coefficients of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I don't understand how equating/comparing coefficients of trigonometric functions and identities works. I will use this question as an example. The question is as follows.

Use the basic definition of periodicity to show algebraically that the period of $f(x) = \sin(nx)$ is $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ for all $n > 0$.

The answer I got is as follows:

The period of a function $f(x)$ is the smallest $p > 0$ such that $f(x+p) = f(x)$
\begin{gather*} \therefore \sin[n(x+p)] = \sin(nx) \\ \therefore \sin(nx+np)=\sin(nx) \\ \therefore \sin(nx) \cos(np) + \cos(nx)\sin(np) = \sin(nx) \end{gather*}
Here is the part where I need help with. The answer in the book continues as follows:

Equating coefficients of $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$,
\begin{gather*}
\cos(np) = 1,\sin(np) = 0  \\
\therefore np = 2k\pi, k \subset \Bbb R \\
\therefore p = \frac{2k\pi}{n}, k \subset \Bbb R
\end{gather*}

I just don't understand how they came to the conclusion that $\cos(np) = 1$ and that $\sin(np) = 0$.Can someone explain?

Comment: You have a typo after $\therefore$.

Comment: @Bernard To be more specific, after the third $\therefore$. At least, that's where I saw a typo.

Comment: The logical structure of your argument makes no sense. The "therefore's" don't belong where you've written them

Comment: @Arthur: Yes. I focused on this specific place, and did't even see  the others…

Comment: What the proof is using is that if $A\sin \theta + B \cos \theta = C \sin \theta + D \cos \theta$ for all $\theta$, then $A = C$ and $B = D$. This is *sort of* intuitive by just looking at them. The proper reason is linear independence, but you could also argue as follows: since the equality holds for all $x$, substitute in $x = 0$ and $x = \pi/2n$ to get your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple: in
$$\sin nx\cos np+\cos nx\sin np,$$
the functions $\sin nx$ and $\cos nx$ (as functions of $x$) are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd line of working is:

$ \therefore \sin(nx) \cos(nx) + \cos(nx)\sin(np) = \sin(nx) $

However, you've made a "silly mistake" here. It should say,

$ \therefore \sin(nx) \cos(np) + \cos(nx)\sin(np) = \sin(nx) $

Now we've got that sorted, see Bernard's answer.

For a proof of Bernard's answer, i.e. to show that that $\sin(u(x))$ and $\cos(u(x))$ are independent, see: [Linear independence of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269668/linear-independence-of-sinx-and-cosx)

Comment: Yep I noticed that mistake just edited it out